# jQuery: set focus on text input nearest to a clicked link

Tags: jquery, focus

OK, I've got kind of a tricky one I'm hoping somebody who is smarter than I am can help with.

I'm building a mobile demo for a client that has a bunch of mini articles on a page. Each article has a share button, and a list of comments. When you click on a share link in an article, it pops open an overlay with a few different options. One of them is "leave a comment". When you click that link, it should close the overlay, unhide the comment field in the article, and set focus on it. I can't figure out how to do that without making a separate overlay for each article, and adding id's to all of the text boxes (which obviously I don't want to do).

[Demo link](http://bit.ly/1kLxyNp)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tactics/XE6Vv/)

Right now, clicking the comment link unhides all the comment fields, and sets focus on the last one on the page. Here's the relevant script for the comment link:

```
$("#comment").click(function() {
$("#overlay").toggleClass('show').toggleClass('hidden');
$(".comment-body").toggleClass('show').toggleClass('hidden');
$(".comment-body").focus();
});
```

Comment: the demo you posted is not easy to edit, why do we have to use elements inspector while you can prepare some code and put it in some [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [jsbin](http://jsbin.com)?

Comment: OK, this is my first try with this, hopefully I got it right. 

http://jsfiddle.net/tactics/XE6Vv/1/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach that comes to mind is to add some means of identifying the overlay-triggering element, for example adding a class, `'overlayTrigger'` to that element:

```
/* overlays */
$("a.icon-postmenu").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('overlayTrigger');
    $("#overlay").load("inc/share-links.php");
    $("#overlay").toggleClass('show').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

And, in the click handler for the overlay element focus the text-input wrapped in the same parent as that element:

```
// selecting the 'a' element with the 'overlayTrigger' class:
$('a.overlayTrigger')
    // removing that class:
    .removeClass('overlayTrigger')
    // finding the first ancestor 'div' element:
    .closest('div')
    // finding the descendant 'input' element with the class of 'comment-body':
    .find('input.comment-body')
    // removing the 'hidden' class-name (to show it):
    .removeClass('hidden')
    // focusing that field:
    .focus();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XE6Vv/3/).

Incidentally, this:

```
/* overlays */
$("a.icon-postmenu").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('overlayTrigger');
    $("#overlay").load("inc/share-links.php");
    $("#overlay").toggleClass('show').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Can be rewritten, to avoid calling `toggleClass()` twice:

```
/* overlays */
$("a.icon-postmenu").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('overlayTrigger');
    $("#overlay").load("inc/share-links.php");
    $("#overlay").toggleClass('show hidden');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XE6Vv/4/).

Edited to correct my -mistakenly- leaving your own pre-existing code, alongside my own, to attempt to do the same thing. Now removed, to give:

```
$("#comment").click(function () {
    $("#overlay").toggleClass('show').toggleClass('hidden');
    $('a.overlayTrigger').removeClass('overlayTrigger').closest('div').find('input.comment-body').toggleClass('hidden').focus();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XE6Vv/6/).

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the toggle, I'm kind of new to to jQuery. The fiddle *almost* works right now. When you click the comment link, it unhides all of the comment boxes (not just the one in the article you want to comment on).

Comment: Upon further testing, there's actually a few problems with this. One is the inputs aren't hidden and reset after a comment is added. The bigger problem though is this: add a comment to the first article. Then repeat the process for the second article, but with a different comment. It doesn't post the new comment, it posts the same comment again.